# JVM C1 and C2 Compile Time Benchmark

Tags: jvm, jvm-hotspot, jvm-arguments

I have simple hello world program, and set `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=[0 to 4]`. I understand the basic difference how it uses either interpreter or C1 or C2 or both C1 and C2 to compile code.

I'd like to know real benchmark details to know compile time, and others details if i use different numbers.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I'd like to know the real bench mark using the different levels. Is there any details from you Andrei?

Comment: I read the question several times, but still can't make sense of it, sorry. Can you paraphrase it? Do you want to compare the compilation time of C1 vs. C2? The compilation of a particular Java method, or any random method?

Comment: sorry for that, now modified. yes compile time and also any signifcant difference.

Comment: `time java -Xcomp -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=N` - a simple way to compare compilation time of bootstrap classes. See also [`CompilationMXBean.getTotalCompilationTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/CompilationMXBean.html#getTotalCompilationTime())

Comment: I get ```1.27s user 0.11s system 83% cpu 1.651 total``` like this. Could you please let me know which one is compile time?

Comment: You can use the `-XX:+CITime` to get compilation times from the different compilers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To benchmark JIT compilers, use `-Xcomp` to force compilation of all executed methods, and check [`CompilationMXBean.getTotalCompilationTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/CompilationMXBean.html#getTotalCompilationTime()) to find the total time spent in JIT compilation.

#### Example

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class CompilationTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getCompilationMXBean().getTotalCompilationTime());
    }
}
```

**C1**

```
$ java -Xcomp -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 CompilationTime
162  // milliseconds
```

**C2**

```
$ java -Xcomp -XX:-TieredCompilation CompilationTime
1129  // milliseconds
```

Comment: yeah Andrei, i used the sample and got it also.